# Is "fastly" a correct word?

Tags: adverbs, is-it-a-word

*Slow* has the adverb *slowly*. I tend to use *fastly* as the adverb for *fast*.

However, it is underlined in most spell checkers I use, which makes me wonder about the existence of this word.

Is *fastly* a correct word? If not, what should be used instead, and why is that different from its antonym?

Comment: No need to apologize, this site is for people like yourself that are interested in improving. The sad fact is that many native English speaks don't understand "trivial" concepts, and don't care about being correct. You should be proud of the fact that you even asked.

Comment: Those native English speaks ought to be ashamed of themselves.

Comment: Check out this video from Merriam-Webster on flat adverbs: http://www.merriam-webster.com/video/0030-flatadverbs.htm?&t=1312554289

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/602308/2085).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is no need for "fastly" because "fast" is both an adjective and an adverb.  So, "I ran fast" is completely correct.

The existence of "fast" as an adverb does not preclude the future development of a word "fastly", but it does hinder it.

One might note that the corresponding adjective "slow" *does* take the *-ly* suffix, but this has no impact on the behavior of "fast".  (There is also no real reason why, for example, we have warm/warmth, but cool/coolness. Semantically related things sometimes have similar morphological patterns, and sometimes not.)

---

One interesting thing worth noting (that was brought up in a comment by Jimi Oke) is that there are cases of adjectives with identical adverbs that *also* have an *-ly* form; for example, we have "right" and "wrong" as adjectives and adverbs, but we also have "rightly" and "wrongly".  In such cases, the *-ly* form has carved out its own semantic niche; the adverb "right" and the adverb "rightly" cannot be used interchangeably in every situation.  I can say "turn right" and "rightly so", but I can't exchange them in either sentence.

With normal adjectives that cannot become adverbs without *-ly*, usually the *-ly* just transparently makes the adjective adverbial — it doesn't have its own separate semantic nuances (e.g. "quickly" simply means "in a quick manner").

Comment: Er...I beg to differ. I drove quickly, but the car was fast. Fast is an adjective not an adverb. The adverb is quickly.

Comment: You could, however, be stuck fast. I've no idea what part of speech 'fast' is in that context.

Comment: As I said, "fast" can be an adjective *or* an adverb.  "The car was fast. The car drove fast." Both are correct.  You can even check the dictionary if you don't trust me: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fast .

Comment: Indeed, I see no difference between "the car was going fast" and "the car was going quickly."

Comment: Imagine if a pedant insisted that you could not say "How fast does this car go?" because you ought to say "How quickly does this car go?"  I think "quickly" actually sounds silly there.

Comment: Could you say: How quick does this car go? Or should be Quickly? cause quickly sounds silly indeed.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Indeed, there is no *fastly*, but I don't quite agree with the reason you give. Is there a rule that says one cannot add *-ly* to adverbs that are also adjectives? Because, *right* and *wrong* are two adverbs that are also adjectives, and *-ly* can be added to both.

Comment: @Jimi Oke: I guess I could have said, "there is no *need* for 'fastly'".  Along the lines of your examples, we also have "first" and "firstly".  I think you'll agree, though, that "rightly" and "wrongly" (and "firstly") have their own special domains of use — you can't just choose "right" or "rightly" whenever you want.  So, there is no need for "rightly" *as the adverb counterpart for "right"*; instead it exists because it adds a different nuance of meaning of its own (as opposed to e.g. "quick" and "quickly" which you could say *only* differ in their part of speech).

Comment: @Jimi Oke: I just wanted to add that you make a good observation; definitely worth clarifying!

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Thanks :) Oh yes, *quick/quickly* falls into a different class entirely. So, I'm guessing that's what you based your *fast/fast* argument on. However, I must confess I am still puzzled by the rest of your answer. What does *warm/warmth*, etc, have to do with *slow/slowly*, or the main point of your answer?! This is a genuinely curious question, mind! :)

Comment: @Jimi Oke: The point of those examples is that, just because there is a certain morphological pattern for one word, that doesn't mean that word's opposite should have an analogous pattern.  That is, just because *slow-slowly* is a pattern, that doesn't mean that *fast* can only be an adjective unless it becomes *fastly*.  Make sense?  I think I might reword my answer to improve it based on your questions :)

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Thanks for your patience! Got it now :)

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I just discovered how *old* this question and your answer were! It came up as one of the active questions today and I erroneously thought you'd just posted your response! Had I known this, I'd have simply let sleeping dogs lie. Thanks for the recognition and for actually taking the time to edit an old answer :)

Comment: Are you sure about this? I find "I ran fast" to sound grammatically incorrect, but that may just be the strict (and sometimes wrong) education I was raised on. I wouldn't feel comfortable writing that in a formal situation.

Comment: @jjackson: I am 100% certain. [Any dictionary will back this up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fast?show=1&t=1296179742).

Comment: so lastly is also word for last?

Comment: @Brian Hooper I don't know what's happened in the intervening years, so this may not be appropriate. Of course _fast_ is an adjective in _I have a fast car_ / _My new car is very fast._ But it's the semantically similar adverb in _He drives too fast._ This may be more informal than _He drives too quickly_, but is probably more idiomatic.

Answer (score 12):

The adverb form of fast is irregular. It is one of several exceptions, as is "well" as mentioned by Dena A.

```
a fast runner   /    run fast
a hard worker   /    work hard
a bad smell     /    smell bad
```

etc. etc. etc.

About work hard: 'he works hard', in contrast to 'he is hardly working'. Two different meanings.

Comment: Small note... *bad* is not an irregular adverb in this case, it is an adjective with irregular verb behavior (see rule 2 of http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/adjAdv.asp).  You could say "smell badly" to talk about being unable to smell properly.

Answer (score 6):

*Fast* is an adverb as well as an adjective, so you wouldn't use *fastly*. Another common adverb that doesn't follow the pattern of ending in *ly* is *well*, not the expected *goodly*, which is actually an adjective and means a large quantity, e.g. *a goodly sum*.

Comment: *Love* and *lovely* follow this pattern as well I guess. (Not too sure, though.) *Love* is a noun/verb and *lovely* is an adjective.

Answer (score 5):

Per etymonline, [fastly](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=fastly&searchmode=none) is the 'former adverbial form of *fast* (adj.), from O.E. *fæstlic* "firm, fixed, steadfast, resolute;" obsolete in 19c., simple *fast* taking its place.'

There you go folks, so much for logic...

Answer (score 2):

Though word `fastly` used in many places (you can find many results by searching [Google](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&q=fastly)) but still it is not correct.
For reference see the definition of word `fast` from [WikiDictionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fast)

See the post [`wrong / fast-- adverbs with no 'ly' ending`](http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst1349_wrong---fast---adverbs-with-no--ly--ending-.aspx) to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

This reminds me of how small children extrapolate grammatical constructions in seemingly logical ways, except English is not always that logical.

So my daughter (3¾) will correctly say "I colour in neatly" or "I'll do it carefully", but then also "It comes lastly" "I can hop bigly" "Go farly" "Squeeze me hardly" etc.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, *fastly* is a word alright. It just happens to be an obsolete one.

Answer (score 1):

"Fast" can also mean to hold onto in a strongly, and "fastly" is the adverb of that word. E.g. "The crew held **fastly** onto the hand-rail of the boat as it rolled in the storm"

Comment: I wouldn't say that, and google gives 118 hits for "held fastly", as against 298 000 for "held fast".

Another adjective which is also an adverb is "hard". "Hardly" exists, but has a completely different meaning.

Comment: Sorry, but "fastly" just isn't a word. You drive fast. You hold fast to the handrail of the boat. You hold fast to an idea. You can also drive quickly, but that's the same as driving fast.

Comment: As said from Kosmonaut too, _fast_ is already an adverb, and the suffix _-ly_ is used to create an adverb from an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

This is emblematic of a misunderstanding that gives rise to forms truly abominable, begetting debellished hypercorrections thusly seen in casual prose all over the internet todaily.

The problem is that people oftenly get this mistaken notion that adverbs need to end in *‑ly*. I know no likely explanation for this blunder, but they stilly do it anywaily.

Howeverly certain they are of this non-rule, nothing could be furthlier from the truth, and the soonlier they realize this, the morely their writing stands to gain; it sure won’t happen beforely.

This semisilly answer is intended to come across friendlily, not meanly or worsely.

Comment: Ha ha ha ha! Awesome answer! (I know comments like this are against the rule, but I just couldn't help appreciating your witty answer!)