# How to express worry about a near date?

Tags: time, dates

Let's say John and I agreed that at April 6h he and I would have a work done. Thus, I would like to send him an e-mail saying something like this:

> Hi John,
>
> 1. the agreed date is approaching. Do you have any news for me?
> 2. the agreed date is coming. Do you have any news for me?
> 3. we are quickly reaching the agreed date. Do you have any news for me?

How could I express this and sound like an American native speaker?

Comment: Hi  John, as  the deadline date is drawing near, I wonder if  you have news for me?

Comment: @thiagoh Note that you should have said: *John and I agreed....* (http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32439/and-me-versus-and-i) and regarding *fastly*, see: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/is-fastly-a-correct-word

Comment: Firstly, 'fastly' isn't really a word http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/is-fastly-a-correct-word Re your actual query, if the concern is that *you* will not have time to do your part of the work if John doesn't hurry up with his, then say so. consider something like 'Our deadline is fast approaching, can you give me an update on progress? I have a number of other commitments pending and need to ensure I can block out sufficient time for this one.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rewrite it as the following. I partly agree with @Josh, except I would change his version to "As the deadline is drawing near, I was wondering if you have any news for me" (as opposed to "deadline date", which in my opinion is a bit redundant).

> As the agreed-upon date/deadline is quickly/rapidly approaching, I was wondering if you have any news/updates for me.

Note that in the above sentence, it's your choice whether you use "quickly" or "rapidly", "date" or "deadline", or "news" or "updates". I just thought I'd give you some more options to work with.